# Push_swap: sorting a given set of numbers in ascending order in C, using two rotatable stacks with limited instructions

Tags: c, sorting, push-swap

I was given [this school 42 task](https://github.com/byaliego/push_swap/blob/main/en.subject-pushswap.pdf):

> You have at your disposal a set of int values, 2 stacks and a set of instructions to manipulate both stacks.
>
> Write [a program] in C:
>
> [...] called `push_swap` which calculates and displays on the standard output the smallest program using `Push_swap` instruction language that sorts integer arguments received: [...]
>
> - `sa`: swap `a` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `a`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `sb`: swap `b` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `b`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `ss`: `sa` and `sb` at the same time.
> - `pa`: push `a` - take the first element at the top of `b` and put it at the top of `a`. Do nothing if `b` is empty.
> - `pb`: push `b` - take the first element at the top of `a` and put it at the top of `b`. Do nothing if `a` is empty.
> - `ra`: rotate `a` - shift up all elements of stack `a` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rb`: rotate `b` - shift up all elements of stack `b` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rr`: `ra` and `rb` at the same time.
> - `rra`: reverse rotate `a` - shift down all elements of stack `a` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrb`: reverse rotate `b` - shift down all elements of stack `b` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrr`:  `rra` and `rrb` at the same time.

So I have to place numbers in stack `a` and then sort them in ascending order using these two stacks `a` and `b`.

#### My sorting function

```
void    sorts_stack(stack *a, stack *b)
{
    int     srt;

    srt = is_not_sorted(a);
    if (srt)
    {
        if (a->list[srt] == top(a) && a->list[srt] > a->list[0])
        {
            rotate_ra_rb(a->list, a->size); //ra : rotate a
            putstr("ra\n");
        }
        else if (a->list[srt] == top(a) && a->list[srt] > a->list[srt - 1])
        {
            swap_sa_sb(a->list, a->size);//sa : swap a
            putstr("sa\n");
        }
        else if (a->list[srt] > a->list[srt - 1])
        {
            putstr("pb\n"); //pb : push b
            push_pb(a, b);
        }
        sorts_stack(a, b);
    }
    else if (b->size > 0)
    {
        if (top(a) < top(b))
        {
            push_pa(a, b); //pa : push a
            putstr("pa\n");
        }
        else if ((top(a) > top(b)) && b->size != 0)
        {
            push_pa(a, b); //pa : push a
            putstr("pa\n");
        }
        sorts_stack(a, b);
    }
}
```

My function sorts the stack, but it takes too many steps to sort. I need suggestions or advice on how to make it sort the stack with less steps taken.

[complete online code -- broken link](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/d0ujw1)

Comment: @Polikdir how is this a duplicate?, the two questions are totally different.

Comment: There are actually 13 operations,  missing is `top(a)` and `top(b)` , as seen in the complete online code.

Comment: @rcgldr, `top(a)` and `top(b)` do not count as "operations" here, as the challenge is only interested in the output (which consists of operations that can be re-executed to sort the input), not how you achieved that output. In theory you could look at every value of the stack (not only the top) and make comparisons in all possible directions before deciding what operation to output.

Comment: The code link has been changed, it is now  [complete online code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/d0ujw1).

Comment: @trincot - then the containers should not be called stacks.

Comment: The list of operations already makes clear this is not about ordinary stacks. This code challenge is usually implemented with circular linked lists. But the essential thing here is that the coder can use any data structure they want, any algorithm they want, as long as the output it produces can be reused by another (verifying) program to check whether the instructions in the output would correctly sort the input.

Comment: @trincot - geeksforgeeks may be helpful for student learning, but some of their tutorial examples are relatively inefficient, and despite their statement "if there is a better way ... please comment", in general those comments end up getting deleted, instead of geeksforgeeks improving their tutorials.  LeetCode | Stack Overflow | Stack Exchange are better sites to get tutorial examples.

Comment: I completely agree with your assessment of geeksforgeeks. Not sure why you are telling me though. This is not a Geeksforgeeks challenge. You wrote yourself in your answer that it is a challenge by school 42.

Answer (score 2):

Given two stacks A and B, where A is filled with a random permutation of elements and B is empty, and one temporary variable T able to hold one element (and a counter but the counter doesn't count) you can sort A in ascending order into B by:

1. move all elements from A to B but keep the largest element in T
2. move all elements from B to A
3. put element in T on the stack B
4. Loop until A is empty

   1. move all elements from A to B but keep the largest element in T
   2. move all elements from B to A except the biggest one(s) on the bottom (here is the place where the counter comes handy to keep the number of already sorted elements in B)
   3. put element in T on the stack B

You can (and should) put all of it in a single loop, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a student project challenge from school 42 (not accredited) called "push swap". `a` and `b` are not stacks. Generally a set of integers is read into an array for the sort logic, then copied into `a`. `a` and `b` are typically implemented as circular doubly linked lists. The 11 allowed operations include swap and rotate, which are not native stack operations. Additional arrays can be used in order to generate a set of operations to sort the set of integers in `a`.

Link to a answer to a later posting of the same question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75115367/3282056

---

This was my prior answer, that assumed that no other arrays could be used to help generate a set of commands, limiting the result to using 4 of the 11 operations to implement a two queue merge sort.

This is really a two queue problem, since the rotate operations effectively turn a stack into a queue (push + rotate == queue push back). In this case a bottom up merge sort can be performed, which would be relatively fast.

Using a linked list or circular (instead of a linear array) to implement the stack / queue would speed up the rotates.

---

Bottom up merge sort for 2 queues:

Initial split: Pop elements off the original queue, and appended elements alternately to the original and temporary queue. Set queue size to number of elements popped off original queue. Set sorted run size to 1.

Merge sort pass: Set two local remaining queue size variables = the two queue sizes to determine the end of a merge sort pass. Each move decrements remaining queue size. Set a local destination variable for which queue to initially move elements to (if last pass, set to move to `a`).

Merge a pair of runs: Set two local remaining run size variables to MIN(run size, remaining queue size). Each move decrements a remaining run size. If one of the remaining run sizes is zero, move the rest of the other run and break, else merge a pair of elements. Repeat until one of the run sizes is zero.

End of merge a pair of runs: Toggle the destination variable so the next two runs are merged to the other queue. Repeat until both remaining queue sizes are zero.

If size of `b` is zero, merge sort is done, else double the run size and do another merge sort pass.

Comment: You're missing some important details.  If the number of numbers is not a power of 2, you'll need at some point to have different numbers of runs on the two sides, and after that at least one run that is of different size from the others.

Comment: @btilly - I updated my answer to include more details.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution in Java.

```
public class SortStack {

    Stack<Integer> stack1;
    Stack<Integer> stack2;    

    public Stack<Integer> sort(Stack<Integer> stack) {
        this.stack1 = stack;
        stack2 = new Stack<>();
        putSmallestAtBottom();
        empty2BackTo1();
        return stack1;
    }

    private void putSmallestAtBottom() {
        /*Pop a number from stack1
        * Compare it top item in stack2
        * If stack2 item is bigger, move it stack1
        * Keep doing this
        * Once thats done push that smaller num to stack 2
        * Keep repeating until stack 1 is empty*/
        while (stack1.isEmpty() == false) {
            int num = stack1.pop();
            while (stack2.isEmpty() == false && stack2.peek() > num) {
                stack1.push(stack2.pop());
            }
            stack2.push(num);
        }
    }

    private void empty2BackTo1() {
        while (stack2.isEmpty() == false) {
            stack1.push(stack2.pop());
        }
    }    
}
```