# segregate even odd number using two stacks

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

I have two stacks. One stack is empty and other stack contains a list of numbers. We need to segregate even odd numbers such that one stack contains even numbers and other stack contains odd numbers only. I am unable to find any optimal solution with O(n) or O(nlogn) -- time complexity and O(1) -- space complexity . Please help.

Comment: I doubt this might be done in O(n). Quadratic in the worst case - yes, possible.

Comment: Can you share your approach ? @MBO

Comment: (`O(logn)` no way sequentially (and a stack *is* sequential access). `O(n)` You can even get the initially empty stack contain *all* the numbers of one selected flavour, but you get to keep only O(1) of the complementary ones.)

Comment: See also: [O(n²) selection sort using two stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165092).

Comment: `unable to find any optimal solution with O(nlogn)` try and prove the problem needs O(n²) steps, worst case, at least.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) time but you would need a third stack, so O(n) extra space in worst case. I was thinking in terms of bit manipulation to make it O(1) space, but kinda stuck with moving numbers here and there.

Comment: Does the definition of "stack" allow to read & write `stack[i]` for any `i` that is within range?

Comment: @trincot Even if it does, wouldn't that be against the definition of stack itself?

Comment: @vivek_23, that is circular: my question is about the definition of stack in this question.

Comment: @trincot Not sure if I understood you correctly. What I meant is if you could access stack[i] for a given i in O(1) time, then it ain't following a LIFO structure anymore. Maybe you can have them in a map, then the current question won't need stacks.

Comment: @vivek_23, it just depends on what the OP has in mind when talking about stacks, since there is no O(n) solution when those stacks would only offer pop & push, and nothing else. I just need clarification from the OP about what exactly *they* mean with "stack". We all know that programming languages typically offer a more rich interface in their stack implementations.

Comment: @trincot I get it now. I was just curious with `stack[i]` and `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Quadratic approach. Let stack A contains values, B is empty.

Pseudocode:

```
while not A.Empty:
   x = A.Pop
   if IsOdd(x):
       while not B.Empty and IsEven(B.Peek):
           A.Push(B.Pop)
   B.Push(x)
while not B.Empty and IsEven(B.Peek):
    A.Push(B.Pop)
```

Now A contains even items, B contains odd ones.