# Push_swap: what is the most efficient way to sort given values using a limited set of instructions on two rotatable stacks?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stack, language-agnostic, push-swap

I have an inferior solution for the [push_swap project for school 42](https://github.com/byaliego/push_swap/blob/main/en.subject-pushswap.pdf):

> You have at your disposal a set of int values, 2 stacks and a set of instructions to manipulate both stacks.
>
> Write [a program] in C:
>
> [...] called `push_swap` which calculates and displays on the standard output the smallest program using `Push_swap` instruction language that sorts integer arguments received: [...]
>
> - `sa`: swap `a` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `a`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `sb`: swap `b` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `b`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `ss`: `sa` and `sb` at the same time.
> - `pa`: push `a` - take the first element at the top of `b` and put it at the top of `a`. Do nothing if `b` is empty.
> - `pb`: push `b` - take the first element at the top of `a` and put it at the top of `b`. Do nothing if `a` is empty.
> - `ra`: rotate `a` - shift up all elements of stack `a` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rb`: rotate `b` - shift up all elements of stack `b` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rr`: `ra` and `rb` at the same time.
> - `rra`: reverse rotate `a` - shift down all elements of stack `a` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrb`: reverse rotate `b` - shift down all elements of stack `b` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrr`:  `rra` and `rrb` at the same time.

I know an almost identical question as already been asked
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164849/sorting-a-stack-in-ascending-order-in-c-using-two-stacks),
but I do not find the
provided answers to be very helpful since the goal of the exercise was not clearly stated in the question (in its original version).

I have designed a simple algorithm to solve the exercise described above, but it is too slow. How can I improve it or
design a more efficient algorithm?

The goal of the exercise is to find the shortest list of stack instructions such that when followed, stack A is sorted. **What matters most is the size of the list, not the complexity of the algorithm we use to find such a list.**

### Algorithm

For now I have implemented this very simple algorithm :

- Gather all the numbers in the array and sort it such that the
  smallest number is at index 0.
- Take the first number in the sorted array, we'll call it x. We need to move x to the top of the stack then push it to B so :

  - If x is in second position, swap.
  - If x is closer to the top of the stack, rotate until x is on top.
  - If x is closer to the bottom of the stack, reverse until x is on top.
- After each operation check if the stack is sorted.

  - If it is not, push the first element of the stack onto B, take the next element in the array and repeat.
- When only two elements are left in A, check if they are ordered, if not swap them.
- Push all the elements from B back onto A.

This algorithm works pretty well when n is small but takes way too long when n gets large. On average I get :

- 30 instructions for n = 10.
- 2500 instructions for n = 100.
- 60000 instructions for n = 500.
- 250000 instructions for n = 10000.

I would like to go below 5000 steps for n = 500 and below 500 steps for n = 100.

Comment: This isn't really a C programming question, so the C code provided is quite irrelevant.

Comment: That's true but I thought it would be better to provide as much detail as possible instead of too little and having to edit the post to add more.

Comment: BTW, you list of operations does not contain any comparison/condition operations, which are must for sorting. The problem description seem to be incomplete

Comment: ... nor to read the value of any element on either stack.  You need to be able to do this in order to perform your array-based bubble sort.  (Relying on which seems like a cheat.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger It could be done "blindly", if provided some conditional operations such as "swap-if-greater" and similar.

Comment: Yes, @EugeneSh., the given problem could be solved with only those additional operations, but what I said was that they do not suffice to implement *the approach proposed by the OP* (at least as I understand that).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @JohnBollinger I should have made it clearer, but the goal of the exercise is to print to the screen the smallest set of instructions which will sort the stack A. Therefore I don't think it is necessary to have comparison/condition operations like Eugene Sh. suggested.

Comment: @EugeneSh. After re-reading your comments I decided to make the question more explicit and language agnostic.

Comment: Random access to a stack such as yours costs O(N) stack operations.  Your approach uses N such operations, for an overall cost of O(N * N) stack operations.  A divide and conquer approach more along the lines of a merge sort could do the job with fewer operations in most cases, and you have answer describing exactly such an approach.

Comment: Since the problem changed, I updated my solution with a number of ideas for further optimization.  Based on back of the envelope estimates, I think 6000 steps is doable.

Comment: The title and question should be changed if this is the `push swap` challenge from `school 42` . Although called a stack, it's not a stack, it's an array, and it is allowed to be copied to external array, and additional arrays can be used. Such as using a second external array of indexes to produce a sorted set of indexes. A stack can't be rotated, but a queue, circular array, or circular linked list can.

Comment: See also [Lowest possible estimated number of steps or time complexity for push_swap program for 42](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77228485/5459839) with an implementation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question needs to be edited. The exercise is called "push swap", a project for students at school 42 (non-accredited school). A second part of the project is called "checker" which verifies the results of "push swap".

Here is a link that describes the push swap challenge | project. Spoiler alert: it also includes the authors approach for 100 and 500 numbers, so you may want to stop reading after the 3 and 5 number examples.

https://medium.com/@jamierobertdawson/push-swap-the-least-amount-of-moves-with-two-stacks-d1e76a71789a

The term stack is incorrectly used to describe the containers *a* and *b* (possibly a French to English translation issue), as swap and rotate are not native stack operations. A common implementation uses a circular doubly-linked list.

push swap: input a set of integers to be placed in *a*, and generate a list of the 11 operations that results in *a* being sorted. Other variables and arrays can be used to generate the list of operations. Some sites mention no duplicates in the set of integers. If there are duplicates, I would assume a stable sort, where duplicates are to be kept in their original order. Otherwise, if going for an optimal solution, all permutations of duplicates would need to be tested.

checker: verify the results of push swap.

Both programs need to validate input as well as produce results.

One web site lists how push swap is scored.

```
required: sort   3 numbers with <=     3 operations
required: sort   5 numbers with <=    12 operations
scored:   sort 100 numbers with <=   700 operations   max score
                                     900 operations
                                    1100 operations
                                    1300 operations
                                    1500 operations   min score
scored:   sort 500 numbers with <=  5500 operations   max score
                                    7000 operations
                                    8500 operations
                                   10000 operations
                                   11500 operations   min score
```

The following gives an idea of what is allowed in an algorithm to generate a list of operations. The first step is to convert the values in *a* into ranks (the values are never used again). In the case of duplicates, use the order of the duplicates when converting to ranks (stable sort), so there are no duplicate ranks. The values of the ranks are where the ranks belong in a sorted array:

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sorted[rank[i]] = rank[i].
```

For example, the values {-2 3 11 9 -5} would be converted to {1 2 4 3 0}: -2 belongs at sorted[1], 3 at sorted[2], ..., -5 at sorted[0]. For a stable sort where duplicates are allowed, the values {7 5 5 1 5} would be converted to {4 1 2 0 3}.

If *a* has 3 ranks, then there are 6 permutations of the ranks, and a maximum of 2 operations are needed to sort *a*:

```
{0 1 2} : already sorted
{0 2 1} : sa ra
{1 0 2} : sa
{1 2 0} : rra
{2 0 1} : ra
{2 1 0} : sa rra
```

For 5 ranks, 2 can be moved to *b* using 2 operations, the 3 left in *a* sorted with a max of 2 operations, leaving at least 8 operations to insert the 2 ranks from *b* to into *a*, to end up with a sorted *a*. There only 20 possible ways to move 2 ranks from *b* into *a*, small enough to create a table of 20 optimized sets of operations.

For 100 and 500 numbers, there are various strategies.

Spoiler:

Youtube video that shows 510 operations for n=100 and 3750 operations for n=500.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aMrmWOgLvU

Description converted  to English:

> ```
> Initial stage :
>  - parse parameters
>  - Creation of a stack A which is a circular doubly linked list (last.next = first; first.prec = last
>  - Addition in the struct of a rank component, integer from 1 to n.
> This will be much more practical later.
> Phase 1 :
>  - Split the list into 3 (modifiable parameter in the .h).
>  - Push the 2 smallest thirds into stack B and do a pre-sort. do ra with others
>  - Repeat the operation until there are only 3 numbers left in stack A.
>  - Sort these 3 numbers with a specific algo (2 operations maximum)
> Phase2:
>  (Only the ra/rra/rb/rrb commands are used. sa and sb are not used in this phase)
>  - Swipe B and look for the number that will take the fewest moves to be pushed into A.
>  There are each time 4 ways to bring a number from B to A: ra+rb, ra+rrb, rra+rb, rra+rrb. We are looking for the mini between these 4 ways.
>  - Then perform the operation.
>  - Repeat the operation until empty B.
> Phase 3: If necessary rot stack A to finalize the correct order. The shorter between ra or rra.
> The optimization comes from the fact of the maximum use of the double rotations rr and rrr
> ```

Explanation:

> ```
> Replace all values in a by rank.
> For n = 100, a 3 way split is done:
> ranks 0 to 32 are moved to the bottom of b,
> ranks 33 to 65 are moved to the top of b,
> leaving ranks 66 to 99 in a.
> I'm not sure what is meant by "pre-sort" (top | bottom split in b?).
> Ranks 66 to 99 in a are sorted, using b as needed.
> Ranks from b are then inserted into a using fewest rotates.
> For n = 500, a 7 way split is done:
> Ranks 0 to 71 moved to bottom of b, 72 to 142 to top of b, which
> will end up in the middle of b after other ranks moved to b.
> Ranks 143 to 214 to bottom of b, 215 to 285 to top of b.
> Ranks 286 to 357 to bottom of b, 358 to 428 to top of b.
> Leaving ranks 429 to 499 in a.
> The largest ranks in b are at the outer edges, smallest in the middle,
> since the larger ranks are moved into sorted a before smaller ranks.
> Ranks in a are sorted, then ranks from b moved into a using fewest rotates.
> ```

Comment: I know you are not the author of the description, but do you have any idea what the author meant by "Push the 2 smallest thirds into stack B and do a pre-sort"? What are the two smallest thirds? The two thirds in which the sum of the ranks is the smallest? The thirds with the least elements?

Comment: @Emperor_Udan - I updated my answer, and added an explanation for the video.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165541/585411 which you already rejected. But hopefully you'll understand my explanation of how to do a bottom up mergesort better.

A **run** is a group of numbers in sorted order.  At first you have many runs, presumably most are of small length.  You're done when you have one run, in stack `A`.

To start, keep rotating `A` backwards while the bottom element is `<=` the top.  This will position the the start of a run at the top of `A`.

Next, we need to split the runs evenly between `A` and `B`.  The way we do it is go through `A` once, looking for runs.  The first run goes at the bottom of `A`, the second run goes at the bottom of `B`, and so on. (Placing at the bottom of `A` just needs `ra` until the run is done. Placing at the bottom of `B` means `pb` then `rb`.)

Once we've split the runs, we either just placed a run at the bottom of `A` and `A` has one more run than `B`, or we just placed a run at the bottom of `B` and they have the same number of runs.

Now start merging runs, while you continue switching between `A` and `B`.  Every time you merge, if you merged to `A` then `A` wound up with one more run.  If you merged to `B` you have the same number of runs.

Merging a run to `B` looks like:

```
if top of A < top of B:
    pb
rb
while bottom of B <= top of B:
    if top of A < top of B:
        pb
    rb
while bottom of B <= top of A:
    pb
    rb
```

Merging a run to `A` is similar, just reversing the roles of the stacks.

Continue until `B` is empty.  At that point `B` has 0 runs, while `A` has one.  Which means that `A` is sorted.

This algorithm will take `O(n log(n))` comparisons.

---

The problem has changed a lot since I first answered, so here are ideas for optimizations.

First, when splitting, we can do better than just dealing runs to `A` and `B`.  Specifically we can put rising runs at the bottom of `A`, and push falling runs onto `B` (which leaves them rising).  With an occasional `sa` to make the runs longer.  These operations can be interleaved, so, for instance, we can deal out `5 2 3 1 4` with `pb ra ra pb ra` and then merge them with `pa ra ra ra pa ra` thereby sorting it with 11 operations.  (This is probably not optimal, but it gives you the idea.)  If you're clever about this you can probably start with an average run length in both piles of around 4 (and maybe much better).  And during the splitting process you can do a lookahead of several instructions to figure out how to efficiently wind up with longer runs.  (If you have 500 elements in runs of 4 that's 125 runs.  The merge sort pass now should be able to finish in 7 passes.)

Are we done finding potential optimizations?  Of course not.

When we start the merge passes, we now have uneven numbers of runs, and uneven numbers of elements.  We are going to merge pairs of runs, place them somewhere, merge pairs again, place them somewhere, etc.  After the pass is done, we'd like two things to be true:

1. The average length of run in both stacks should be about the same (merging runs of similar lengths is more efficient).
2. We want to have used as few operations as possible.  Since merging `n` into `m` takes `2n+m` operations, it matters where we put the merge.

We can solve for both constraints by using dynamic programming.  We do that by constructing a data structure with the following information:

```
by the number of merged runs created:
    by the number of runs put in `A`
        by the number of elements put in `A`
            minimal number of required steps
            last stack merged into
```

We can then look through the part with the largest number of runs created, and figure out what makes the average run size as close as possible.  And then walk back to figure out which sequence of merges got there in the minimum number of steps.  And then we can work out what sequence of steps we took, and where we wound up.

When you put all of this together, I'm dubious that you'll be able to sort 500 elements in only 5000 steps.  But I'd be surprised if you can't get it below 6000 on average.

And once you have all that, you can start to look for better optimizations still.  ("We don't care how much analysis is required to produce the moves" is an invitation to spend unlimited energy optimizing.)

Comment: Apparently, it's not the number of comparisons that needs to be optimized, but rather the number of stack operations.  My intuition is that this will nevertheless do better than the OP's approach, but it's not quite clear to me whether the number of stack ops will be O(n log n).

Comment: @JohnBollinger It will be.  The initial split of runs will take `O(n)` stack operations. Leaving `O(n)` runs. We're cycling through both stacks in parallel.  Each rotation takes at most `2n` stack operations, and cuts the number of runs in half. After `O(log(n))` rotations we're down to one run with `O(n log(n))` stack operations.

Comment: Great, I accept that.  However, I think this statement from the answer is wrong: "Every time you merge, if you merged to `A` then `A` wound up with one more run. If you merged to `B` you have the same number of runs."  Isn't it rather the case that each time you merge a pair of runs, in either direction, you end up with one *fewer* run in the source stack, and one fewer overall?

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, that's right. Each time you merge, you destroy one run from each stack, and create a merged run in the stack you merge to. That reduces the other stack by 1. So if `A` and `B` both have 99 runs, you merge to `A` leaving `B` with 98. Then merge to `B` leaving them tied at 98. Then merge to `A` leaving `B` with 97.  Then merge to `B` leaving them tied at 97.  And so on until `A` has 1 run and `B` has 0.

Comment: Yes.  I think that's what I said, too, but the answer itself does not seem to be saying the same thing.  At least, I'm having trouble reading the answer that way.

Comment: OH, I see.  You mean A ends up with one more run **than B**, not one more run than A previously had.  That's not a natural reading of the answer's wording for me, but ok.

Comment: Following the questions limitations to a stack interface, doesn't bottom(b) require rrb | top(b) |  rb | ? Also if using > compare to indicate end of run, then multiple sorted runs can appear as one run if they just happen to be in order, the code would need to handle this and the sort would not be stable.

Comment: @rcgldr It looks like operations to read the value are free. A previous version of the question indicated there was a data structure to keep track of the values top and bottom. So that manipulation seems unlikely to be needed.

Comment: @rcgldr Look for the word `register` in the very first version of the problem.

Comment: Assuming this is the push swap challenge from school 42, the so called stack a is allowed to be scanned or copied. I updated my answer.