# Lowest possible estimated number of steps or time complexity for push_swap program for 42

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, push-swap

I am looking at the [following code challenge](https://github.com/byaliego/push_swap/blob/main/en.subject-pushswap.pdf):

> #### The “push_swap” program
>
> You have to write a program named push_swap which will receive as an argument a stack formatted as a list of integers. The first argument should be at the top of the stack (be careful about the order).
>
> The program must display the smallest list of instructions possible to sort the stack, the smallest number being at the top.
>
> Instructions must be separated by a `\n` and nothing else.
>
> The goal is to sort the stack with the minimum possible number of operations. During defence we’ll compare the number of instructions your program found with a maximum number of operation tolerated. If your program either displays a list too big or if the list isn’t sorted properly, you’ll get no points.
>
> In case of error, you must display Error followed by a `\n` on the standard error. Errors include for example: some arguments aren’t integers, some arguments are bigger than an integer, and/or there are duplicates.
>
> #### Game rules
>
> The game is composed of 2 stacks named `a` and `b`.
>
> To start with:
>
> - `a` contains a random number of either positive or negative numbers without any duplicates.
> - `b` is empty
>
> The goal is to sort (in ascending order) numbers into stack `a`.
>
> To do this you have the following operations at your disposal:
>
> #### Commands and Description of Each Command:
>
> - `sa`: swap `a` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `a`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `sb`: swap `b` - swap the first 2 elements at the top of stack `b`. Do nothing if there is only one or no elements).
> - `ss`: `sa` and `sb` at the same time.
> - `pa`: push `a` - take the first element at the top of `b` and put it at the top of `a`. Do nothing if `b` is empty.
> - `pb`: push `b` - take the first element at the top of `a` and put it at the top of `b`. Do nothing if `a` is empty.
> - `ra`: rotate `a` - shift up all elements of stack `a` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rb`: rotate `b` - shift up all elements of stack `b` by 1. The first element becomes the last one.
> - `rr`: `ra` and `rb` at the same time.
> - `rra`: reverse rotate `a` - shift down all elements of stack `a` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrb`: reverse rotate `b` - shift down all elements of stack `b` by 1. The last element becomes the first one.
> - `rrr`:  `rra` and `rrb` at the same time.
>
> #### Example
>
> The example below sorts integers in stack `a` in 10 instructions.
>
> ```
> Init a and b:
> 2
> 1
> 3
> 6
> 8
> 5
> _ _
> a b
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Exec sa:
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 6
> 8
> 5
> _ _
> a b
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Exec pb pb pb:
> 6 3
> 5 2
> 8 1
> _ _
> a b
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Exec rr:
> 5 2
> 8 1
> 6 3
> _ _
> a b
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Exec rrr:
> 6 3
> 5 2
> 8 1
> _ _
> a b
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Exec sa:
> 5 3
> 6 2
> 8 1
> _ _
> a b
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Exec pa pa pa:
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 6
> 8
> _ _
> a b 
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

#### Analysis

I ran a visualizer (https://github.com/o-reo/push_swap_visualizer) on the code at https://github.com/Kuninoto/42_push_swap/tree/master/lvl_2_push_swap. (The file names at https://github.com/Kuninoto/42_push_swap/tree/master/lvl_2_push_swap/srcs/algos show "insertion_sort.c", "midpoint_sort.c", "radix_sort.c" and "special_case.c".)

main.c

```
#include "push_swap.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_stack a;
    t_stack b;

    if (argc < 2)
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    a = init_stack(argc - 1);
    fill_a(&a, parse_input(argc, argv, &a), argc);
    b = init_stack(argc - 1);
    if (!is_sorted(&a))
    {
        if (a.stack_size == 3)
            special_case(&a);
        else if (a.stack_size >= 200)
            radix_sort(&a, &b);
        else
            midpoint_sort(&a, &b);
    }
    free_stacks(&a, &b);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

radix_sort.c

```
#include "push_swap.h"

static void simplify_numbers(t_stack *stack, int *sorted_array)
{
    int i;
    int *temp;
    int j;

    i = -1;
    temp = malloc(stack->stack_size * sizeof(int));
    while (++i < stack->stack_size)
    {
        j = -1;
        while (++j < stack->stack_size)
        {
            if (sorted_array[i] == stack->storage[j])
                temp[j] = i;
        }
    }
    i = -1;
    while (++i < stack->stack_size)
        stack->storage[i] = temp[i];
    free(temp);
    free(sorted_array);
}

static int  *gen_sorted_arr(t_stack *stack)
{
    int *sorted_arr;
    int i;

    sorted_arr = malloc(stack->stack_size * sizeof(int));
    i = 0;
    while (i < stack->stack_size)
    {
        sorted_arr[i] = stack->storage[i];
        i += 1;
    }
    insertion_sort(sorted_arr, stack->stack_size);
    return (sorted_arr);
}

void    radix_sort(t_stack *a, t_stack *b)
{
    int max_bits;
    int num;
    int i;
    int j;

    max_bits = 0;
    simplify_numbers(a, gen_sorted_arr(a));
    num = max(a);
    while ((num >> max_bits) != 0)
        max_bits++;
    i = -1;
    while (++i < max_bits)
    {
        j = -1;
        while (!is_sorted(a) && (++j < a->stack_size))
        {
            num = a->storage[a->top];
            if (((num >> i) & 0b00000001) == 1)
                ra(a, true);
            else
                pb(a, b);
        }
        while (!is_empty(b))
            pa(a, b);
    }
}
```

midpoint_sort.c

```
#include "push_swap.h"

int find_midpoint(t_stack *stack, int chunk_start)
{
    int     mid_point;
    int     i;
    int     chunk_size;
    int     *sorted_arr;

    mid_point = 0;
    i = 0;
    chunk_size = (stack->top + 1) - chunk_start;
    sorted_arr = malloc(chunk_size * sizeof(int));
    while ((i + chunk_start) < (stack->top + 1))
    {
        sorted_arr[i] = stack->storage[i + chunk_start];
        i += 1;
    }
    insertion_sort(sorted_arr, chunk_size);
    mid_point = sorted_arr[(chunk_size / 2)];
    free(sorted_arr);
    sorted_arr = NULL;
    return (mid_point);
}

void    midpoint_sort(t_stack *a, t_stack *b)
{
    int chunks;
    int mid_point;

    chunks = 1;
    if (ok_sa(a))
        sa(a, true);
    while (a->top > 1)
    {
        mid_point = find_midpoint(a, 0);
        move_smaller_top(a, b, mid_point);
        move_smaller_bottom(a, b, mid_point);
        finish_moving(a, b, mid_point, chunks++);
    }
    if (a->storage[a->top] > a->storage[a->top - 1])
        sa(a, true);
    while (b->top != -1)
        move_bigger_top(b, a, max(b));
}
```

- For 500 integers, the result ranges from 6740 to 6960 steps.
- For 9 integers, the result ranges from 24 to 33 steps.
- For 5 integers, the result ranges from 7 to 13 steps.
- For 4 integers, the result ranges from 5 to 8 steps.
- For 3 integers, the result ranges from 1 to 2 steps.

I tried regression using the maximum number of steps obtained above (for 3, 4, 5 and 9 integers) and the linear equation ("max_steps = 5.108n - 12.8", where n = number of integers to sort, rSquared of 0.999) gives 2541 steps for 500 integers.

### Question

I am wondering if a better algorithm really exists and if the result is possible to be as low as 2541 for 500 integers. Wrote out a few cases by hand for 4 integers or 5 integers but could not figure out the lowest possible estimated number of steps or time complexity.

Comment: Please include all relevant info inline in your question, not via links.

Comment: `ss`, `rr` and `rrr` combine pairs of actions which seems to suggest these pairs count as one action only, yet in the example they are not counted as one. Also [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KW59UO55TQ&ab_channel=JOHNPARK) doesn't present them as combined actions. So do they count as one or not? If not, they should not be in the list. If they do count as one, the example is misleading.

Comment: @trincot. `rr` is counted as one step. `ra` and `rb` are counted as 2 steps. Thanks for helping to edit my post. 

Comment: I find this a really interesting challenge. But the question still lacks information (see first comment above). There is a link to a github project, but you do not give any information about the algorithm it uses, and provide no code. Such details must be reproduced inside the question (not behind a link). For instance, the code might perform different steps for smaller input sets, and so performing an extrapolation would then be meaningless. Please also provide the exact formula you have used for this extrapolation.

Comment: @trincot. I am hoping that even without any code, someone here can figure out the lowest possible estimated number of steps or time complexity. For Kuninoto's code that I used, you have to go into the lvl_2_push_swap folder and the sub-folders. The file names at https://github.com/Kuninoto/42_push_swap/tree/master/lvl_2_push_swap/srcs/algos show "insertion_sort.c", "midpoint_sort.c", "radix_sort.c" and "special_case.c".

For the extrapolation, I used Linux LibreOffice Calc (similar to Microsoft Excel) and got "max_steps = 5.108n - 12.8", where n = number of integers to sort.

Comment: You have added a section of text that is mostly duplicating what is already in the preceding paragraphs.

Comment: I must repeat that although links are interesting as background information, the essential stuff should be embedded in the question. If there is code you refer to and ask about, the relevant code should be inside the question.

Comment: By lack of reaction, I have removed the duplicate text you entered.

Comment: Can you please reply and update your question? Having an exchange with intervals of days instead of minutes is not really going to work well. You list several sorting algorithms. Which one is the basis for your statistics? And what is the description of the algorithm (either a thorough description, or pseudo code, or actual code)? This should not be behind a link, but inside your question.

Comment: @trincot. My apologies for not replying promptly and not inserting the code in this page (because I think it's messy to insert so much code here and the code may not be relevant since it's possible to answer my question without the code). I just realised from https://github.com/Kuninoto/42_push_swap/blob/master/lvl_2_push_swap/main.c that the code used:

special.c for n = 3,

midpoint_sort.c for n = 4 to n = 199 and

radix_sort.c for n >= 200.

You are right that my "using regression on n = 3, 4, 5 and 9 to extrapolate for n = 500" is meaningless.

Comment: Your realisation proves all the more that there is *essential* information behind links that is lacking in your question. Please add all *relevant* information in your question. This is how Stack Overflow works. I understand this means you will need to sift through code and decide what is relevant and what is not. It requires some effort on your side to make this a quality question.

Comment: Thank you for having added the relevant code! Do you expect an answer to provide code in c specifically, or is this an algorithm question for which an answer may present an algorithm in pseudo code or other programming language?

Comment: @trincot. You're welcome.  Pseudo code or code in any programming language is fine.

Comment: OK, I went for JavaScript, because then you can run it on the spot here. See addition to my answer.

Comment: @trincot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the main function actually selects a different sorting algorithm depending on the size of the input, it makes little sense to try to extrapolate the number of operations on small data sets to larger data sets.

It is also an unwarranted assumption that there is a *linear* relation between the number of operations for sorting in terms of the input size: for larger inputs, it uses [the radix sort implementation](https://github.com/Kuninoto/42_push_swap/blob/master/lvl_2_push_swap/srcs/algos/radix_sort.c) you quoted.

In the worst case `is_sorted(a)` will not be true at an earlier stage, and then we have an outer loop of log and an inner loop performing an operation for each value in stack A (which always initially has all values). That algorithm produces therefor O(log) operations, not O().

You write:

> For 500 integers, the result ranges from 6740 to 6960 steps.

On the question whether a better algorithm exists, here is one:

#### Algorithm

First phase:

- Determine the median of stack A. Call the set of values that are less than that median X, and the set of the remaining values Y.
- Determine the median of X.
- Move all values in X that are less than the second median to the bottom of stack B and all values in X that are greater than that median to the top of stack B. Values in Y should just rotate to the bottom of stack A.
- Now stack A has half its original size, and stack B has two partitions: its top half has values that are all greater than its bottom values
- Repeat the above until A is only left with 3 values. Sort those three values. Stack B will end up with several partitions of varying size. The outermost partitions will have the greatest values, and the innermost will have the lesser values.

Second phase:

In this phase stack A will always be circularly sorted, i.e. it only needs rotations to be sorted.

- Repeatedly take a value from stack B and insert it into the sorted index in stack A, i.e. at the single position where the above invariant is not broken. Calculate which one of the possible candidate values in Stack B requires the least operations to do that. Both stacks may need rotations: B rotates the chosen value to its top, and A rotates to bring the desired insert position at its top. If either stack was rotated to retrieve and accept the value, these rotations don't need to be reversed after the push. Make use of the combined operators (`rr`, `rrr`) when possible.
- Repeat the above until stack B is empty.
- Rotate stack A so that its greatest value is at the bottom.

To extend this to undefined larger inputs, you would need to apply the split into partitions multiple times, switching stacks to repeat a similar phase as the first one, and acting on large partitions to split them up into smaller ones. Acceptable sizes for partitions are up to about 450. When partitions get much larger than that you need to add a partitioning from stack B to A, ...etc. I will not dwell on this, as your question seems to target inputs of up to 500 values, but it is an essential step to achieve an acceptable asymptotic complexity.

Note that this challenge does not look for an optimal time complexity of the *algorithm*, but of the *output size*. So in theory you can spend as much time as you want to try different methods/parameters to get the input sorted and finally take the one that turns out best.

#### Implementation

Below is an implementation. I chose JavaScript so I could provide a runnable snippet here. Some of the characteristics:

- A circular linked list class for the stacks.
- A PushSwap class as the combination of two stacks.
- A class to collect the actions (ra, rb, ...etc). Its `optimise` method finds some common patterns that can be reduced to a shorter list of actions. For instance, it will replace `ra` rotations when fewer `rra` can achieve the same. Or, it will eliminate two consecutive `sa`, ...etc.
- The actions are grouped into `ActionNode` objects, which is a set of rotations (multiple rotations on one or both stacks) and a final (single) push or swap. This makes it easier to spot optimisations that concern rotations (grouping some of them into `rr` or `rrr`).
- The solver will run three times with different bucket sizes, selecting the shortest output.

#### Snippet:

```js
// Utility functions:
const mod = (a, b) => b ? ((a % b) + b) % b : 0;

function shuffle(a) {
    for (var i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

function normalise(values) { // Map values to their index when sorted
    const res = Array(values.length);
    values.map((a, i) => [a, i])
          .toSorted(([a], [b]) => a - b)
          .forEach(([,val], i) => res[val] = i);
    return res;
}

class CircularLinkedList {
    static Node = class {
        constructor(value, after=null) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = after?.next ?? this;
            this.prev = after ?? this;
            this.next.prev = this.prev.next = this;
        }
        detach() {
            if (this.next === this) return null;
            this.next.prev = this.prev;
            this.prev.next = this.next;
            return this.prev;
        }
    }
    constructor(values) {
        this.topNode = null;
        this.length = 0;
        // First value should become the top of the stack -- Push in reverse order
        for (let i = values?.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            this.push(values[i]);
        }
    }
    push(value) {
        this.topNode = new CircularLinkedList.Node(value, this.topNode);
        this.length++;
    }
    pop() {
        if (!this.topNode) return;
        const value = this.topNode.value;
        this.topNode = this.topNode.detach();
        this.length--;
        return value;
    }
    get top() {
        return this.topNode?.value ?? null;
    }
    *topDown() {
        if (!this.topNode) return;
        let node = this.topNode;
        do {
            yield node.value;
            node = node.prev;
        } while (node != this.topNode);
    }
    *topDownEntries() { 
        let i = 0; // Index starting at top
        for (const value of this.topDown()) {
            yield [i++, value];
        }
    }
    *bottomUp() {
        if (!this.topNode) return;
        let node = this.topNode.next;
        while (node != this.topNode) {
            yield node.value;
            node = node.next;
        }
        yield node.value;
    }
    // Extra savepoint feature
    getSavepoint() {
        return {
            topNode: this.topNode, // Might be detached later, but we can still walk back into the actual list
            bottomNode: this.topNode?.next,
            length: this.length,
        }
    }
    restoreSavepoint(savepoint) {
        const {topNode, bottomNode, length} = savepoint;
        this.length = length;
        this.topNode = topNode;
        if (!topNode) return;
        topNode.next = bottomNode;
        for (let node = topNode; node.prev.next !== node; node = node.prev) {
            node.next.prev = node.prev.next = node;
        }
    }
}

class RotatableLinkedList extends CircularLinkedList {
    get bottom() {
        return this.topNode?.next?.value ?? null;
    }   
    rotate(steps=1)  { // Rotate with given number of steps (can be negative)
        if (this.length < 2) return;
        steps %= this.length;
        for (; steps > 0; steps--) this.topNode = this.topNode.prev;
        for (; steps < 0; steps++) this.topNode = this.topNode.next;
    }
    swap()  { // Swap two top elements
        if (this.length < 2) return;
        [this.topNode.value, this.topNode.prev.value] = [this.topNode.prev.value, this.topNode.value];
    }
    *zigzag() { 
        // Yield entries in order of the number of ra or rra rotations needed to get them to the top:
        //    Negative ra values indicate rra instead of ra.
        const n = this.length;
        const props = ["next", "prev"];
        const nodes = [this.topNode, this.topNode.prev];
        for (let ra = 0, i = 0; i < n; ra += ++i % 2 ? i : -i) {
            yield [ra, nodes[i % 2].value];
            nodes[i % 2] = nodes[i % 2][props[i % 2]];
        }
    }
}

const NONE = 0, PUSH = 1, SWAP = 2;

class ActionNode {
    constructor(rotsA, rotsB=0, mutation=NONE, target=0) {
        // The given rotations are supposed to occur first, and then either a swap or push can occur.
        this.rots = [rotsA, rotsB]; // Signed integers for ra (rra) and rb (rrb)
        this.mutation = mutation; // NONE, PUSH or SWAP
        this.target = target; // 0 or 1, i.e. stack number
    }
    is(rotsA, rotsB=0, mutation=NONE, target=0) {
        return (rotsA === null || this.rots[0] === rotsA) 
            && (rotsB === null || this.rots[1] === rotsB)
            && (mutation === null || this.mutation === mutation) 
            && (mutation === NONE || target === null || this.target === target);
    }
    numActions() {
        return (this.rots[0] * this.rots[1] < 0
                        ? Math.abs(this.rots[0]) + Math.abs(this.rots[1]) 
                        : Math.max(Math.abs(this.rots[0]), Math.abs(this.rots[1]))
               ) + (this.mutation !== NONE);
    }
    *getActionNames() {
        const ra = Math.max(0, this.rots[0]);
        const rb = Math.max(0, this.rots[1]);
        const rr = Math.min(ra, rb);
        const rra = Math.max(0, -this.rots[0]);
        const rrb = Math.max(0, -this.rots[1]);
        const rrr = Math.min(rra, rrb);
        for (let i = rr;  i < ra;  i++) yield "ra";
        for (let i = rr;  i < rb;  i++) yield "rb";
        for (let i = 0;   i < rr;  i++) yield "rr";
        for (let i = rrr; i < rra; i++) yield "rra";
        for (let i = rrr; i < rrb; i++) yield "rrb";
        for (let i = 0;   i < rrr; i++) yield "rrr";
        if (this.mutation !== NONE) yield " ps"[this.mutation] + "ab"[this.target];
    }
    set(a, b, mutation, target) {
        return new ActionNode(a ?? this.rots[0], b ?? this.rots[1], 
                                mutation ?? this.mutation, target ?? this.target);
    }
    insert(stack, direction, mutation, target) {
        return this.set(this.rots[0] + (1-stack)*direction,
                        this.rots[1] + stack*direction,
                        mutation, target);
    }
}

class ActionStack extends CircularLinkedList {
    constructor(stackSize) {
        super();
        this.numActions = 0;
        this.sizes = [stackSize, 0];
    }

    getSavepoint() {
        return {
            ...super.getSavepoint(),
            numActions: this.numActions,
            sizes: [...this.sizes],
        }
    }
    restoreSavepoint(savepoint) {
        super.restoreSavepoint(savepoint);
        this.numActions = savepoint.numActions;
        this.sizes = [...savepoint.sizes];        
    }

    addRotation(stack, direction)  { return this.add( (1-stack)*direction,  stack*direction) }

    add(rotsA, rotsB=0, mutation=NONE, target=0) {
        return this.addNode(new ActionNode(rotsA, rotsB, mutation, target));
    }
    addNode(node) {
        // Optimise node
        node = this.optimiseNode(node);
        if (!node) return this; // Nothing to do
        // Add the node...
        this.push(node);
        this.numActions += node.numActions();
        if (node.mutation === PUSH) {
            this.sizes[node.target]++;
            this.sizes[1-node.target]--;
        }
        // ...and then see if optimisations are possible
        return this.optimise();
    }
    popNodes(count=1) {
        while (count-- > 0) {
            const node = this.pop();
            this.numActions -= node.numActions();
            if (node.mutation === PUSH) {
                this.sizes[node.target]--;
                this.sizes[1-node.target]++;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
    optimiseNode(curr) {
        if (!curr.numActions()) return null; // Remove useless node
        // Push or Swap that has no effect?
        if (curr.mutation === PUSH && this.sizes[1-curr.target] === 0 || 
                curr.mutation === SWAP && this.sizes[curr.target] < 2) {
            return this.optimiseNode(curr.set(null, null, NONE, 0));
        }
        // Can rotations be made more optimal if inverted?
        let [a, b] = curr.rots;
        let [alen, blen] = this.sizes;
        a = mod(a, alen);
        b = mod(b, blen);
        // The four different possibilities:
        let best = 0;
        let bestCost = alen + blen;
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            const c = i >= 2 ? Math.abs(a - alen) : a;
            const d = i % 2  ? Math.abs(b - blen) : b;
            const cost = c + d - (i % 3 > 0 ? 0 : Math.min(c, d));
            if (cost < bestCost) {
                bestCost = cost;
                best = i;
            }
        }
        // Get best possibility
        if (best > 1) a -= alen;
        if (best % 2 == 1) b -= blen;
        // is this the one actually used?
        if (a !== curr.rots[0] || b !== curr.rots[1]) return this.optimiseNode(curr.set(a, b));
        // A swap on a stack of size two: convert to rotation
        if (curr.mutation === SWAP && this.sizes[curr.target] === 2) return this.optimiseNode(curr.insert(curr.target, 1, NONE, 0));
        return curr;
    }
    optimise() {
        const curr = this.topNode.value;
        const prev = this.topNode.prev.value;
        const prevPrev = this.topNode.prev.prev.value;
        const stack = 1-curr.target;
        const numRotations = curr.rots[stack];
        if (this.length > 0) {
            // Case: move other-stack rotations forward to the other side of sa (and its mirror case): 
            if (curr.mutation === SWAP && numRotations !== 0) {
                // Move rotations forward into a new node
                return this.popNodes(1) // * sa
                           .addNode(curr.insert(stack, -numRotations)) // sa
                           .addRotation(stack, numRotations); // *
            }
        }
        if (this.length > 1) {
            // Cases: rotation sequences that can merge into one node
            if (this.length > 1 && prev.mutation === NONE) {
                return this.popNodes(2)
                           .addNode(curr.set(curr.rots[0] + prev.rots[0], curr.rots[1] + prev.rots[1]));
            }
            // Cases: pb pa (or: sa sb) (and their mirrors)
            if (curr.is(0, 0, prev.mutation, prev.mutation === PUSH ? 1 - prev.target : prev.target)) { 
                // opposite push/swaps with no rotations between them: they cancel eachother
                return this.popNodes(2) // pb pa (or: sa sb)
                           .addNode(prev.set(null, null, NONE, 0)); // mutation deleted
            }
            // Case: pa ra rrb pa => rrb pa pa ra
            const dir = curr.target ? 1 : -1;
            if (curr.is(-dir, dir, PUSH, curr.target) && prev.is(null, null, PUSH, curr.target)) {
                return this.popNodes(2) // pa, ra-rrb-pa
                           .addNode(prev.insert(1-curr.target, -1)) // rrb pa
                           .add( 0,  0, PUSH, curr.target) // pa
                           .addRotation(curr.target, 1); // ra
            }
            // Case: ra pb rra => sa pb (and its mirror)
            const swapSide = 1-prev.target;
            if (prev.mutation === PUSH && prev.rots[swapSide] > 0 && curr.rots[swapSide] < 0) {
                return this.popNodes(2) // ra-pb, rra
                           .addNode(prev.insert(swapSide, -1, SWAP, swapSide)) // sa
                           .addNode(new ActionNode(0, 0, PUSH, 1-swapSide))  // pb
                           .addNode(curr.insert(swapSide, 1));  // -rra
            }
        }
        if (this.length > 2) {
            // Case: pb sa pa => ra sa rra (and its mirror)
            if (prevPrev.is(null, null, PUSH, stack) 
                    && prev.is(0, 0, SWAP, curr.target) && curr.is(0, 0, PUSH, curr.target)) { 
                return this.popNodes(3) // pb sa pa
                           .addNode(prevPrev.set(null, null, SWAP, curr.target).insert(curr.target, 1)) // ra sa
                           .addRotation(curr.target, -1); // rra
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
    dump() {
        const arr = [];
        for (const node of this.bottomUp()) arr.push(...node.getActionNames());
        return arr;
    }
}    

class PushSwap extends RotatableLinkedList {
    constructor(values=[], other=null) {
        super(normalise(values));
        this.log = other?.log ?? new ActionStack(values.length); // Both stacks share same log
        this.other = other ?? new PushSwap([], this); // Back reference
        this.isB = +!!other; // is this stack B? (0 or 1)
        this.stacks = [this, this.other];
        if (other) this.stacks.reverse();
    }
    pushOver()  { // pop value from other stack and push it on this stack 
        this.other.length && this.push(this.other.pop());
    }
    createActionNode(rotation, otherRotation=0, mutation=NONE) {
        if (this.isB) [rotation, otherRotation] = [otherRotation, rotation];
        return new ActionNode(rotation, otherRotation, mutation, this.isB);
    }
    apply(rotation, otherRotation=0, mutation=NONE) {
        return this.applyNode(this.createActionNode(rotation, otherRotation, mutation));
    }
    applyNode(actionNode) { // Action node has absolute stack references (not relative)
        this.stacks[0].rotate(actionNode.rots[0]);
        this.stacks[1].rotate(actionNode.rots[1]);
        if (actionNode.mutation === PUSH) this.stacks[actionNode.target].pushOver();
        if (actionNode.mutation === SWAP) this.stacks[actionNode.target].swap();
        this.log.addNode(actionNode);
        return this;
    }
    // Methods that are (more) specific to the sorting algorithm
    getRotationsNeededForInserting(val) {
        // Assumes that the stack is cyclic sorted.
        // Returns (signed) number of ra needed to get insertion point for val at the top
        let prev = this.bottom;
        for (const [i, next] of this.topDownEntries()) {
            if ((prev < val) + (val < next) === 1 + (prev < next)) return i;
            prev = next;
        }
    }
    rotateLeastToTop() {
        this.apply(this.getRotationsNeededForInserting(-1));
    }
    find(searchValue) {
        for (const [rbCount, value] of this.zigzag()) {
            if (value === searchValue) return rbCount;
        }
    }
    sortBucket(low, remainder, factor) {
        if (remainder <= 0) return this.threeSort();
        let len = this.length + this.other.length;
        // Following values determined statistically. These are parameters that can be played with...
        const firstRatio = 0.33, normalRatio = 0.42, lastRatio = 0.60, limit = 32;

        // An expression to determine the ratio of elements in A that should move as 2 buckets on stack B.
        let ratio = low ? normalRatio + (2/3 - remainder/len)**2 / 2 : firstRatio;
        if (remainder * lastRatio <= limit) ratio = lastRatio;
        ratio *= factor; // Apply some variation to this ratio -- used to get different results to choose from.
        const twoBucketsSize = remainder <= limit ? remainder : Math.ceil(remainder * ratio);

        const topSize = twoBucketsSize >> 1;
        const topBucket = {start: low, end: low + topSize};
        const bottomBucket = {start: low + topSize, end: low + twoBucketsSize};
        const buckets = [bottomBucket, topBucket];

        // Populate the buckets on stack B.
        let delayedR = 0;
        let safety = 1000;
        for (let i = 0; i < twoBucketsSize; i++) {
            let bucket;
            while (!(bucket = buckets.find(bucket => this.top >= bucket.start && this.top < bucket.end))) {
                if (safety-- < 0) throw "safety stop";
                const rb = +(delayedR > 0);
                this.apply(1, rb);
                delayedR -= rb;
            }
            this.other.apply(bucket === topBucket ? delayedR : 0, 0, PUSH);
            delayedR = bucket === topBucket ? 0 : delayedR + 1;
        }
        // Buckets are now populated. Continue with next buckets (recursion)
        this.sortBucket(bottomBucket.end, remainder - twoBucketsSize, 1/factor);
        // Move the values from those buckets back to A in their sorted positions
        this.wheelInsert(bottomBucket);
        this.wheelInsert(topBucket);
        // ...and put the least value at the top
        this.rotateLeastToTop();
    }
    wheelInsert({start, end}) {
        let maxValue = end - 1;
        // Get back a range of values from stack B into stack A
        for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (this.top >= maxValue) maxValue = Math.max(...this.other.topDown()); 
            this.insertBestValue(start, maxValue);
        }
    }
    getTransferMove(rbCount, value, additionalCost=0) {
        // Return action needed to get a value in stack B to its top (given its rb-distance)
        //    and to have the relevant insertion point in stack A at its top also.
        const savepoint = this.log.getSavepoint();
        const action = this.createActionNode(this.getRotationsNeededForInserting(value), rbCount, PUSH);
        const result = { cost: -this.log.numActions + this.log.addNode(action).numActions + additionalCost, action };
        this.log.restoreSavepoint(savepoint); // Remove the above move form the action log
        return result;
    }
    insertBestValue(minValue, maxValue) {
        if (this.other.length === 0) return;
        let best = { cost: Infinity };
        for (const [rbCount, value] of this.other.zigzag()) {
            if (Math.abs(rbCount) > 9 ) break;
            if (value < minValue) continue; // We don't want to touch other buckets
            // Get move to rotate this value to top of B and rotate A to receive that value, and push
            const move = this.getTransferMove(rbCount, value, maxValue - value);
            if (move.cost < best.cost) best = move; // Keep track of cheapest move
        }
        // Perform the move for real now
        this.applyNode(best.action);
    }
    threeSort() { // To sort at most three values remaining on stack A.
        if (this.length === 3) {
            let [a, b, c] = this.topDown();
            if ((a < b) + (b < c) + (c < a) === 1) this.apply(0, 0, SWAP);
        }
        this.rotateLeastToTop();
    }
    static sort(values, bestOf=3) {
        const maxLeftOver = 3; // Number of values to leave on stack A (threeSort depends on it)
        const factors = [1, 1.06, 0.95]; // Factors to vary the bucket sizes
        let bestResult = { length: Infinity };
        for (let i = 0; i < bestOf; i++) {
            const pushSwap = new this(values); 
            // Distribute stack A into buckets on stack B and sort them back into A
            pushSwap.sortBucket(0, pushSwap.length - maxLeftOver, factors[i]);
            pushSwap.rotateLeastToTop();
            const result = pushSwap.log.dump();
            if (result.length < bestResult.length) bestResult = result;
        }
        return bestResult;
    }
}

// I/O 

function animate(values, actions) {
    const resultSizeOutput = document.querySelector("span");
    const intervalInput = document.querySelector("#interval");
    const [a, todo, b] = document.querySelectorAll("td");
    a.innerHTML = todo.innerHTML = b.innerHTML = "";

    function populateTable(table, values) {
        const n = values.length;
        const width = 500;
        const height = Math.max(1, Math.floor(500 / n)) + "px";
        for (const value of values) {
            const bar = document.createElement("div");
            bar.style.height = height;
            bar.style.width = ((value+1)/n*width) + "px";
            bar.style.backgroundColor = "hsl(" + (value / values.length * 245 + 180) + "deg 100% 50%)";
            table.appendChild(bar);
        }
    }
    const insert = (bar, table) => table.children.length ? table.insertBefore(bar, table.firstChild) : table.appendChild(bar);
    const revRotate = table => table.children.length > 1 && insert(table.lastChild, table);
    const rotate = table => table.children.length > 1 && table.appendChild(table.firstChild);
    const swap = table => table.children.length > 1 && insert(table.children[1], table);
    const pushOver = (src, dst) => src.children.length && insert(src.firstChild, dst);

    populateTable(a, normalise(values));
    const n = actions.length;
    let abort;
    todo.innerHTML = "<div>" + actions.join("<br>") + "</div>";
    setTimeout(function loop() {
        if (abort) return;
        const action = actions.shift();
        if (!action) return;
        todo.innerHTML = "<div>" + actions.join("<br>") + "</div>";
        resultSizeOutput.textContent = `${n - actions.length} / ${n}`;
        if (action === "ra" ) rotate(a);
        if (action === "rra") revRotate(a);
        if (action === "rb" ) rotate(b);
        if (action === "rrb") revRotate(b);
        if (action === "rr" ) { rotate(a); rotate(b); }
        if (action === "rrr") { revRotate(a); revRotate(b); }
        if (action === "sa" ) swap(a);
        if (action === "sb" ) swap(b);
        if (action === "ss" ) { swap(a); swap(b); }
        if (action === "pa" ) pushOver(b, a);
        if (action === "pb" ) pushOver(a, b);
        setTimeout(loop, +intervalInput.value);
    }, +intervalInput.value);
    return () => abort = true;
}

function main(PushSwap) {
    const [sizeInput, stackInput] = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    const resultSizeOutput = document.querySelector("span");
    const [randomButton, solveButton] = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    let cancel = () => null;

    randomButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const size = +sizeInput.value || 0;
        stackInput.value = shuffle([...Array(size).keys()]).join(" ");
    });

    solveButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        cancel();
        const values = stackInput.value.match(/-?\d+/g).map(Number);
        const actions = PushSwap.sort(values);
        resultSizeOutput.textContent = actions.length;
        cancel = animate(values, actions);
    });
}

main(PushSwap);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
tr { height: 502px; max-height: 502px; }
table { width: 100%; background: silver; overflow: clip; }
td { width: 49%; vertical-align: top; }
td:nth-child(2) { width: 20px; border: 1px solid }
td:nth-child(2) > div { height: 500px; overflow-y:hidden; }
input[type=number] { width: 4em }
```

```html
Size: <input type="number" value="500" min="3" max="500"><button>Generate</button>
Input: <input><button>Sort</button>
Interval (ms): <input id="interval" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="200">
Actions: <span></span>
<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

#### Performance

This implementation needs 3610 actions on average to sort 500 values.

Comment: That entire argument with time complexity is just wrong. They're not counting comparisons, they're counting stack operations. Let's for a moment not consider stacks but a list and swaps as the operation. A list of n elements can easily be sorted with n-1 or fewer swaps. Doesn't matter if you can't find the swaps in O(n) time. It's the number of swaps that counts. Same here with the stacks.

Comment: OK, Kelly, I removed that paragraph. I just leave it that the author has not given any basis why they performed a linear estimation.

Comment: ...and added an analysis of one of their referenced algorithms which has O(log) complexity.

Comment: Ok, that part looks good now. About your algorithm: What does *"insert it into the sorted index in stack A"* mean? How did you determine the average of 3600-4200 operations? What's the complexity class (for number of operations)?

Comment: Ok I think I understand it now :-). But I have no idea how many operations it takes, other than that it's somewhere between linear and quadratic...

Comment: I have edited to better explain the "sorted index" concept. I have determined the average by executing this algorithm on a thousand random inputs of 500 elements. The first phase has O() complexity, for the second phase I have trouble deriving it, but from sampling it looks worse than O() and it wouldn't surprise me if it turned out to be O(log).

Comment: Oh you've implemented it? Will you share it?

Comment: @trincot. Thank you so much for your answer. Like Kelly Bundy, I would like to have your code (if you are willing to share).

Comment: @Kelly, added an implementation in JavaScript.